# Linq Class in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I created a asp.net web application project and added a linq.cs to App_code folder to access objectDataSource but I got this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Please Help me; I've already tried many techniques but failed every time to resolve this.

Comment: Do you have "using System.Linq; " at the top?

Comment: yes. using System.Linq it is added,

Comment: what version as .net is your project running can you check to make sure that you have something like this in your web.config file
`<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>` this is assuming your are running under 3.5 and not 4.0 or 4.5 also because it's added to the using, also make sure it's actually added under the references section for the project and check the namespace of the linq.cs file that you said you added.. tell us what the namespace is

Comment: ooo yes that was the issue.. Problem solved... THANX EIGavilan

Comment: assembly was required in web.config

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe your missing using system.Linq namespacing. This would allow you access to the classes you need to use linq.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of this error.

Comment: @MuddassirNayyer Yes, it really is.